# How to Mock a python function that returns another callable function?

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, python-mock

I'm using a library that has a function which returns another function.

How can I mock both to test my code using `unittest` and `Mock`? I tried to dig into [unittest doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html), but I'm not finding a similar example.

The example I have:

```py
class Object:
    number = 1

    def mul2(self):
        self.number *= 2

def func_A(x):
    if hasattr(x, 'number'):
        x.mul2()
    return x

def func_B(y):
    return y

obj = Object()
z = func_B(func_A)(obj)
```

I basically need to mock both, but I don't know how to return a callable value to test it. I tried to investigate Mock objects better but I didn't find a good approach for this.

Comment: If you mock `func_B`, it will return a mock which you may configure/set, and it does not make sense to also mock `func_A`. You probably want to mock `func_A`, so the mock would be returned if calling `func_B`. Mocking both does not make sense.

Comment: Can you add an example of what exactly would you like to test?

Comment: @bzu I'm trying to mock a function called dask.delayed. That function is not important, but the behavior of the function I use inside that one. See the doc example: https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/delayed.html

Comment: Wouldn't you want to test either your functions that go into `dask.delayed` separately or the result of the actual dask calculation when calling `.compute()`? I agree here with @MrBeanBremen: if you mock both you will effectively not be testing anything anymore.